# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError saving a Dataset in a file

Tags: java, dataset

I am trying to do a simple Dataset and saving it to a file.

```
    Dataset data = new DefaultDataset();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        Instance tmpInstance = InstanceTools.randomInstance(999);
        data.add(tmpInstance);
    }
    System.out.println(data);
    try {
        net.sf.javaml.tools.data.FileHandler.exportDataset(data, new File("save.data"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
```

The dataset is good created and I can print it, but when trying to save the dataset to a file it fails with the next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: be/abeel/io/GZIPPrintWriter
    at prueba.generador.dataset(generador.java:27)
    at prueba.generador.main(generador.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: be.abeel.io.GZIPPrintWriter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552810/not-able-to-import-abeel-util-in-a-maven-project

Comment: @DoğukanZengin Thanks, but it is not a maven project, is a normal java project :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClassNotFoundException means you are missing a library in the classpath. When we check the missing class, library you need to import is ;

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajt/

After downloading, follow the instructions here

[How do I add jar files to the Classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10386869/4217608)